# NGXS ofActionSuccessful

Tags: ngxs

I have an angular component that subscribes to ofActionSuccessful. This action is dispatched as the user clicks on a button on the page. It is possible that the user may click on this button multiple times resulting in multiple dispatch events for this action

```
 this.actions$.pipe(ofActionSuccessful(UpdateCommunicationPreferences)).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Action Successful');
});

this.store.dispatch(
    new UpdateCommunicationPreferences(this.communicationPreferenceForm.value)
  );
```

The issue that I am running into is ofSuccessful is triggered in an accumulated manner. In other words, the first time the user clicks on the button, the "Action Successful" is printed once. Second time the user clicks on the button, it is printed twice and so forth.

Can anyone help if there is a way to not get duplicate ofSuccessful events for the past actions?

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

This package was developed with your issue in mind:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngxs-labs/actions-executing

@Select(actionsExecuting([UpdateCommunicationPreference])) myActionIsExecuting$: Observable;

you can use myActionIsExecuting$ in your template with async pipe.  you can also simply subscribe to myActionIsExecuting to familiarize yourself with what is returned.  null will be returned when all instances of that particular action are finished.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Jared for the quick response. I am actually interested in subscribing to the action successful events to show the user a confirmation alert of the update that they just intended. While they are on the page, they may end up saving different preferences leading to multiple triggers to this action. I don't think is myActionIsExecuting will help my case.

Comment: Please create a stackblitz to reproduce. I will take a look for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this: https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/cancellation

Extracted from the link: "If you have an async action, you may want to cancel a previous Observable if the action has been dispatched again. This is useful for canceling previous requests like in a typeahead."

---

Alternatively, you can consider a pattern that disables the UI when the button is clicked (e.g. via 'in progress' dialog) before triggering the action dispatch. When the action is done processing, close the dialog.

Hope this helps.